# Is it possible to self-reference type in Python attr

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-attrs

I am looking to do something like this:

```
@attr.s
class A(object):
    a_dict = attr.ib(factory=Dict, type=Dict[str, A], validator=optional(instance_of(Dict)))
```

It is possible to type it just as `type=Dict` but I wonder if you can self-reference like `type=Dict[str, cls]`, but it might be limited by possibilities of Python.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Outer class contains same attributes as ones in split.

Comment: Or do you mean why I want to type it? I just want to be as exact as possible, no particular reason... was just wondering.

Comment: What does `Dict[str, A]` do here?

Comment: its recursive attribute, dict of strings as keys and same class as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret is correctly, what you want is this:

```
from typing import Dict, Optional

import attr

from attr.validators import optional, instance_of


@attr.s
class A(object):
    a_dict = attr.ib(
        factory=dict,
        type=Optional[Dict[str, "A"]],
        validator=optional(instance_of(dict))
    )


A({"key": A(None)})
```

And it passes mypy.

Please note:

- You cannot use `typing.Dict` for `factory` because it's really just for type hints and fails if you try to instantiate it.
- `instance_of` uses `isinstance()` internally and while `isinstance({}, Dict)` is True, I don't think it's the intended to be used like that.
- If a_dict is optional as per validator, you also need to declare it optional using type annotations by wrapping it in an `Optional[]`.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems horribly unpythonic :) . However there seems to be no other way.

Comment: I know this is not super helpful since you're on 2.7, but thanks to PEP 526 in Python 3.7 you can actually omit the quotes if you use `from __future__ import annotations`: https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `class A(object): A` results in `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`. What this means is that one can not reference a class by its name during its creation in its defining block.

I think that to get around this in typing, one can use a string instead: `type=Dict[str, 'A']`. I remember seeing this as how forward references are made but this might not be right.

Answer (score 1):

`cls` and `self` are names given to classes and their instances by convention, when they are passed as arguments to *class methods* and *instance methods* respectively. Neither will be defined where you're trying to use them.

What you might be able to do instead, is enforce the type to be a non-object *superclass* of A, if there is any.